# Hazelcast can't deserialize an enum class

Tags: hazelcast

I'm having some problems with Hazelcast deserialize. I don't know why it is happening to me.

When I build my project with Maven I can see the next error code:

```
GRAVE: Failed to execute callback:     com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy$1@382710c7! Request:     com.hazelcast.map.impl.client.MapGetRequest@cbe959e, response: HeapData{type=-    25,
hashCode=1128451374, partitionHash=1128451374, dataSize=89, heapCost=117}
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to deserialize enum: com.grupo.exception.ExceptionCauseEnum
    at     com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$EnumSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:243)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$EnumSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:225)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.toObject(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:65)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:260)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientCallFuture$1.run(ClientCallFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.grupo.exception.ExceptionCauseEnum
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:124)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:113)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$EnumSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:241)
    ... 9 more
```

ExceptionCauseEnum is in my classpath.

My **Hazelcast instance configuration** (just in case it is useful):

```
<hz:hazelcast id="instance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:group name="${name}"
            password="${pass}" />

        <hz:network port="23456"
            port-auto-increment="true">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast
                    enabled="false"
                    multicast-group="${multicast-group}"
                    multicast-port="${multicast-port}" />
                <hz:tcp-ip enabled="true">
                    <hz:interface>127.0.0.1</hz:interface>
                </hz:tcp-ip>
            </hz:join>
            <hz:interfaces enabled="false">
                <hz:interface></hz:interface>
            </hz:interfaces>
        </hz:network>

        <hz:map name="myMap" max-size="5000" max-idle-seconds="3600" 
            time-to-live-seconds="7200" eviction-percentage="25"
            eviction-policy="LRU" />
    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>
```

Although Maven throws me that error, it builds correctly.

Any idea what is happening and what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see plexus inside the stacktrace. Are you trying to start your application through maven?

Comment: @noctarius Yes I am, I'm building my project with "mvn clean install" command

Comment: But how are you starting it or does it happen while compiling?

Comment: @noctarius it throws that error while it is compiling but I wonder why the project building doesn't fail and finally it shows me BUILD SUCCESS... :S

Comment: Hazelcast is not executed while building. What do you do?

Comment: I start a Hazelcast instance when I build my integration test because my project are using 4 Hazelcast client and it is necessary for a successful building. The "connection" between clients and instance works great but I don't know why happens that error

Comment: There is probably one dependency (maybe client) that doesn't know the enum class

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am also facing similar issue

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem: in my case my enums had a constructor, so my solution was to create a parameterless constructor.